# Why does my meat disappear so quickly in A Dark Room

Tags: a-dark-room

My meat and cured meat supplies disappear as fast as I can collect it, whether from the traps or other means.  I do not currently have thieves.
This makes it difficult to go on journeys.
I've tried adjusting the number of hunters and trappers--but it has not seemed to help.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Miners they will take 1 cured meat per 10s.
If you have Curers they will take 5 wood, 5 meat per 10s (+1 cured meat / 10s).

Each Curer needs to be supported by 10 hunters. So if you have anything more than 3 miners (Which is 3 curers at -15 meat, -15 wood / 10s) you will have a tough time keeping meat levels up.

Personally I run with 30 hunters, 6 curers and 6 miners.
I rely on baited traps to get the excess meat. But you will slowly lose Cured Meat in this way.
The best way to get Cured Meat levels up for exploration is to visit Outposts (`P` on the map) often.